# Trying to use SharedPrefrences and it doesn't work

Tags: java, android

So I see this line being used in all the SharedPrefrences videos and tutorials

`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();`

Only problem is that it doesn't let me do that.

On the .edit() part it tells me I can't reference it since it's a non-static method.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get an actual instance of `SharedPreferences` first for it to work - it looks to me as if you're accessing it as `SharedPreferences.edit()` which then implies the static access.

What's the value of the `sharedPreferences` value you've mentioned? It should probably be something of the likes of the following snippet:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(someContext);
```

Comment: Omg I'm retarded. I did SharedPrefrences sp = getSharedPrefrences(blabla);
and then I didn't use the name I just gave it.
It needed to be sp.edit(); not what I said above...
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Happy to see you figured it out - don't hesitate to mark this as the answer if it helped you find your way. :-)